# How to use Kotlin to copy image data to the Android clipboard?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a string containing the data URI for a PNG image (`"data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...etc"`). How, in Kotlin, do I put the corresponding PNG image onto the Android clipboard?

Background: what I actually have is a `WebView` containing a `<canvas>`. For reasons known only to Google, Javascript in a WebView is not allowed to use `navigator.clipboard`. The suggested workaround is to use `addJavascriptInterface` and pass the data from the WebView into the containing code, which then addresses the clipboard directly rather than doing so from Javascript.

That's easy enough to do with plain text. But I have found precisely zero examples of (a) how to do it with something other than text, or, more generally, (b) how to put anything other than textual data onto the clipboard.

I think I know pieces of the answer. For example, I can take the same string data and construct a `Uri` which stores the image as a file. What I can't find is any information about is creating a Uri which the clipboard will accept as a representation of the image.

Comment: Use `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` pointing to a file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()` on `Context`) that you can use for the clipboard or other operations (e.g., `ACTION_SEND` and `EXTRA_STREAM`).

Comment: I already know how to save files and then use ```ACTION_SEND```. What I can't find is a way in which that is relevant to putting either the file itself or the file contents onto the clipboard.

Comment: Use `FileProvider` to get a `Uri` pointing to a file that [you can use for the clipboard](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/copy-paste#ClipClasses).

Comment: What I know so far is that a ```Uri``` representing a file which is valid for ```ACTION_SEND``` etc is not valid as ```ClipData``` to populate the clipboard. And anything to do with "files" anyway sounds wrong. The entire point is that there is transient image data, and the user wants to put it on the clipboard without creating a file which they don't want and would then need to clean up later.

Comment: "is not valid as ClipData to populate the clipboard" -- perhaps you should edit your question with a [mcve] showing what you tried and explaining your symptoms. "creating a file which they don't want and would then need to clean up later" -- you can put the file in internal storage (e.g., `getCacheDir()` on `Context`) which will not disturb the user. You can then delete the file yourself after some time (e.g., on app start, clear out cache files older than 24 hours), if you choose.

Comment: You are welcome to create a custom `ContentProvider` that holds onto the image in memory and makes it available via some `Uri`. This is risky, in that it implies that the user uses the image off the clipboard before Android terminates your process. A cache file is a simpler and safer solution.

Comment: The normal implementation of a clipboard is that the O/S owns the data, and the data survives termination of the app. That is what happens, for example, with ```ClipData.newPlainText()```. App termination, caching etc shouldn't be an issue. What is egregiously missing in Android is a simple function where, rather than plain text, you can specify a MIME type plus associated data such as a ```ByteArray```. From the 1000s of examples of copying plain text and the zero examples of anything else, it's clear that no-one understands how to use the Android clipboard for anything other than text.

Comment: "What is egregiously missing in Android is a simple function where, rather than plain text, you can specify a MIME type plus associated data such as a ByteArray" -- there are architectural reasons for that, stemming from Android's origins as a mobile operating system supporting low-resource devices. "it's clear that no-one understands how to use the Android clipboard for anything other than text" -- FWIW, I cover using a `Uri` with the clipboard in [this free older book](https://commonsware.com/Android). In my case, the `Uri` is to music, rather than an image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256766/discussion-between-user13473954-and-commonsware).